# Partitions of unity of a compact subset of a smooth manifold

Tags: general-topology, multivariable-calculus, differential-geometry, smooth-manifolds

Let $M$ be a smooth manifold (without boundary if you want). Let $K$ be a compact subset of $M$. Let $\{(U_\alpha,\phi_\alpha)\}_{\alpha=1}^s$ be a finite number of charts of $M$ such that $\{U_\alpha\}$ covers $K$.

> Can I find a smooth partition of unity subordinate to $\{U_\alpha\}$? (i.e. a finite family $\{\rho_\alpha\colon M\to \mathbb{R}\}_{\alpha=1}^s$ of smooth functions such that supp $\rho_\alpha \subseteq U_\alpha$  , im $\rho_\alpha\subseteq[0,1]$, $\{$supp$\rho_\alpha$$\}$ is locally finite and for each point $p\in K$ I have $\sum_\alpha \rho_\alpha(p)=1$   ?

I was thinking of "completing" $\{U_\alpha\}_{\alpha=1}^s$ to an open cover $\{U_\alpha\}_{\alpha\in I}$ of all of $M$ (by adding other charts of my atlas, for example), then taking a smooth partition of unity $\{\rho_\alpha\colon M\to \mathbb{R}\}_{\alpha\in I}$ subordinate to *this* open cover of $M$, then considering only $\{\rho_\alpha\}_{\alpha=1}^s$. But I'm not shure that then I have $\sum_{\alpha=1}^s \rho_\alpha(p)=1$ for each $p$ in $K$.

Comment: The union $\bigcup U_\alpha$ is a smooth manifold itself. Hence, it has a partition of unity subordinate to the $U_\alpha$'s. Then, you can multiply by a cutoff function which is identically $1$ on $K$, and you're done.

Comment: @AmitaiYuval Why not an official answer?

Comment: @AmitaiYuval Thank you. Since I'm a beginner, please let me explain my understanding of your idea. Let $U=\bigcup U_\alpha$. I take a partition of unity $\{\rho_\alpha:U\to \mathbb{R}\}$ subordinate to the cover $\{U_\alpha\}$. Now I take a smooth bump function $\phi:M\to \mathbb{R}$ relative to the pair $(K,U)$, and conseider $\phi_\alpha=\phi\rho_\alpha:M\to \mathbb{R}$. Then $\{\phi_\alpha\}$ is what I have asked, since I have supp$\phi_\alpha \subseteq$ supp$\rho_\alpha \subseteq U_\alpha$ and $\sum_\alpha\phi_\alpha(p)=\sum_\alpha\rho_\alpha(p)=1$ for each $p\in K$ right?

Comment: @Minato Yes, exactly. Now, if you like, you can post your explanation as an answer.

Comment: @AmitaiYuval Thank you very much. But you derserve the answer points :)